# How to fix the error: "resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.example.MyAppName:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found." on vs code

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I need some help to fix that issue I'm facing with my chat app. Everything was working great but I left aside the project for some months.And when I started working on it again,I had to upgrade all the packages and flutter itself so that in hope it works. But I don't know why this error occurs, here the complete error :

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.>
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> D:\MyAppName 2.0\myappname\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:19: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.example.MyAppName:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.

I didn't tried to change any name of icon or anything else, so if someone could help me it will be wonderful. Here are my pubspec.yaml file and my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
   name: MyAppName
    description: A new Flutter project.

    environment:
      sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

    dependencies:
      flutter:
       sdk: flutter
  
    cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4
    flutter_svg: ^1.0.3
    emoji_picker: ^0.1.0
    shared_preferences: ^0.5.4+1
    camera: ^0.9.4+10
    path_provider: ^2.0.2
    path: 
    video_player: ^2.1.6
    socket_io_client: ^1.0.1


    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter



    uses-material-design: true

  
    fonts:
     - family: OpenSans
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
        - asset: fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/OpenSans-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
```

And the AndroidManifest.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.MyAppName"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    <!--
         Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="MyAppName"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.MyAppName.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >

            <!--
                 Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI.
            -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <!--
                 Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame.
            -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.extensions"
            android:required="false" />
        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.sidecar"
            android:required="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

If you need other files to see, there is absolutely no problem ! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it happens because there is a change in flutter. the easy way is to create a new project with the same name, then copy the old files (lib, assets or others) into the project you just created

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, I was importing the icons using:
`Android Studio -> new -> ImageAsset -> choose the image`

But when saving it, I didn't noticed they gave me 3 options to save:
**debug**, **main** or **release**. I was saving in debug, that's why when I went to compile, it didn't search in debug but in **main instead**.

**Solution**: Import the icons from main:
`Android Studio -> new -> ImageAsset -> choose the image -> save to main`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: Import the icons from main:
Right click on mipmap -> new -> ImageAsset -> choose the image -> save to main

**IF these is still the problem**, Right click on mipmap -> Open in -> Eplorer. Then, copy